# What is wrong with my proof that $X$ can't be compact and Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Suppose $(X, \tau)$ is a compact Hausdorff space. Then, $\{x\}$ is closed,
> and $X\setminus\{x\}$ is open. Moreover, $X = \bigcup_{x \in X} X\setminus\{x\} = X
> \setminus \bigcap_{x \in X} \{x\}$. So $\bigcup_{x \in X} X\setminus\{x\}$ is an
> open cover of $X$. But there cannot exist a finite sub cover of
> $\bigcup_{x \in X} X\setminus\{x\}$ because any finite subcover would not
> cover $X$. Hence $X$ is not compact.

I produced this proof when trying to prove that a particular topological space was compact but not Hausdorff. I supposed it was Hausdorff and tried to argue by contradiction. I thought it was correct until I realized it would then allow me to conclude that compact Hausdorff spaces do not exist in  general. I suspect
something is fishy with $X = \bigcup_{x \in X} X\setminus\{x\} = X \setminus \bigcap_{x \in X} \{x\}$, but, after an hour, I still can't spot my mistake? Would be very grateful if someone could point it out to me . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[0,1]$ is compact and Hausdorff and the open cover $\{ X\setminus \{x\} \,:\, x \in X \}$ has finite subcover $\{ X\setminus\{0\} , X \setminus \{1\} \}$